# A sequence of functions that converges to the derivative of the dirac delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations

Consider the sequence $
   r_k(x) =     \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
        k & \mbox{for}
         & |x|<\frac{1}{2k} \\ 0  & \mbox{for} & otherwise 
                \end{array}\right.$

thise sequence has $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle \int_\mathbb{R}r_k f=f(0)$ for any $f \in C^\infty_0$, and so $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}r_k(x)=\delta(x)$ in the sence of disturbution equality. I want to construct a sequnce $(t_k)$ such that this sequence converges to $\delta'(x)$ in the sense of disturbution. I started with saying ok, we need $\displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_\mathbb{R}t_k f=f'(0)$, so why do not I take $t_k=-s_k'$ and then we have $$\int_\mathbb{R}t_k f=s_kf|_{_{- \infty}}^{^{\infty}}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}t_k f'=0-f'(0)$$

but my sequence is not differentiable at each $\frac{1}{2k}, \frac{-1}{2k}.$

I am getting stuck here, and I would appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Try a Gaussian instead of a piecewise function.

Comment: Use as a first approximation $\delta'_0\approx\dfrac{\delta_{h/2}-\delta_{-h/2}}{h}$ and then insert the original delta approximations with $h=1/k$.

Comment: Could you explain more, about how to insert the original delta?